# Is there any difference between a .json, .txt, .html, .css, and .js file other than the extension?

Tags: html, css, json, encoding

The impetus is: I have some JSON that I've been saving as .txt files for a bit.  I'd like to rename them all to .json to be more accurate.  I'm pretty sure they are both UTF-8, as are most files that can be sent over Ajax.

Anyways, this question raised a bigger question.

Is there any real difference between all of these text types, other than the extension?  .html, .json, .css, .js, .txt, .py, etc... they all appear to be the same thing on the inside: a UTF-8 character array.

If you used these interchangeably, would it do anything worse than being confusing?  Do any of these have headers?  Do any of them encode differently when being saved?  Are most .txt files with a different extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you could use what ever suffix you want.The suffix itself does not have an effect on the content of the file. But applications do different stuff depending on the file suffix. So if you use the wrong or an unknown suffix then you need to tell the application about what file type it is, otherwise it would interpret it wrong.

A webserver would by default add `text/html` for a file with the suffix `htm` or `html` as `Content-Type` header. And the client then would interpret the received file as `html` because of that `Content-Type`. So if you add `html` to you JavaScript or CSS files then the client might not execute/use them, even if loaded with `<link>` or `<script>`.

But if you tell the webserver to send `text/css` for `style.html` and `application/javascript` for `script.html` then the client **might** use them correctly. A webbrowser *should* use the `Content-Type` header before guessing the type based on the suffix.

Comment: The only exception here is the `.html` extension. The browser doesn't check  for `content-type` and serves it as `html` based solely on the extension. Try changing an image to `.txt` and it will still open as image. Try changing it to `.html` and it will open as lots of encoded text.

Comment: @Miro the browsers  (at least Chrome, Firefox and Safari) use the `content-type` even if the extension is `.html`, so if you send `image/jpeg` as content type for the url `index.html` they would try to interpret the received data as jpeg.

Comment: @Miro if you do this locally without a webserver then the browser for sure use the file extension, and maybe other informations, because it won't get any `content-type` header. But if you deliver the file using the http protocol, and if you set the `content-type` header in the http response explicitly to e.g. `image/jpeg` for that `.html` file then the webbrowser will use it. I tested it before I wrote my answer, and tested it in those three browser before I wrote the comment.

Comment: @t.niese under those circumstances yes. Fair enough. Yet for some reason an image with extension `.txt` (or any other extension except .html) still opens as image even locally.

Comment: @Miro well you said the browser wouldn't check the `content-type` header for `.html`, but it does. If you open a file without an http sever there is  no `content-type` header to check, so the browser will either only use the file exentsion or it will try to guess the correct type based on the beginning of the content of the file. This is why browser might display a local image even if it has the wrong suffix.

Comment: @t.niese Ah, makes more sense now. In [this demo](http://deepcorelabs.com/projects/so/filetypetest/) all files are the same image but only the `.txt` is recognized as an image. Why?

Comment: @Miro for the given web-server configuration,  the `content-type` header is set based on the file extension. If the webbrowser can correctly interpret the delivered content based on the `content-type`  then it will display the data based on that `content-type`, if the browser has problems in interpreting the data based on the `content-type`  then the result might vary and depend on the browser and system, you should assume that the behavior is then unpredictable and undefined.