# Can a text file and a json file be used interchangeably? And if so how can I use it in python?

Tags: python, json, text

**Question:** I was wondering if JSON and txt files could be used interchangeably in python.

**More Details:**  I found [this](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/protocols-formats/difference-between-json-and-xml/) on the internet and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272587/is-there-any-difference-between-a-json-txt-html-css-and-js-file-other-t) on stack overflow to find what a JSON file is but it did not say if json and txt could be used interchangeably ie using the same commands.  For example, can both use the same code `with open('filename')as file:` or does JSON require a different code.  Also if they can be used in the same general manner is linking and using commands for a JSON file and a txt file the same process?

**OS:** windows 10

**IDE:** IDLE 64-bit

**Version:** Python 3.7

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "used interchangeably", and what, exactly, is *in* the two files.

Comment: A JSON file is a text file; the text it contains is just a specific kind of "code" that represents structured data.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism, I have tried to improve my question.  If it is still not clarified please notify me an I will try to fix it.

Comment: File extensions really only matter to your OS, generally not custom code capable of reading raw bytes of files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.txt` file can contain JSON data, and using `open()` in Python can open any file, with any content, and any file extension (granted the user running the code has permissions to do so)

It's not until you try to load a non JSON string or file using `json.loads` or `json.load`, respectively, where the problem starts.

In other words, a file contains binary data. The data can be represented as a string, that string could be XHTML, JSON, CSV, YAML, whatever, and you must use the appropriate parser to extract the relevant data from that format (but it's not always the file extensions that determine what to use)

> does JSON require a different code

It requires another module

```
import json 
with open(name) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the raw data out of any file the same way; the difference is in reading the structure in the data.